# SSIS 2012 variables with expression evaluate slowly

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a parent package and a child package.
In the parent package I define a variable `ApplicationPath`, which I pass via configurations to the child package.
In the child package I build a new variable called `FilePath` which is set as an expression, `@[User::ApplicationPath] + "myfilename.txt"`

This works, but it takes 3 minutes to evaluate the variable.
I have a script task (for testing and debugging) that produces a message box for each variable. All "normal" variables show immediately, the expression variable takes three minutes to show. (reproducible with breakpoints in the script)

Moreover, even weirder, when I run through the whole workflow of parent package without breakpoints in SSDT it takes:
- less than a second if the child package is already open in SSDT
- up to five minutes if the child package is not open in SSDT, only the parent package.

I really have no idea why it behaves like this. 
Has someone ever come across something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with validation of the child package? I often come across packages that take minutes to open when SSDT is validating the package connections and tasks.
You can set DelayValidation and ValidateExternalMetadata for example, have a look over [here](http://siddhumehta.blogspot.nl/2009/05/validateexternalmetadata-property.html)!

Comment: Hi Nicky, I tried that already, but the problem is actually after validation. Changing the validation options doesn't change anything. It's only as soon as something in the package tries to use the variable with the expression - it still works correctly, but takes 3 to 4 minutes instead of one second.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem - when I switched the evaluation variable from ReadWrite to ReadOnly in the script settings then it suddenly improved the calculation time for me.

Andy